# Most efficient way to bind livewire input with looped/nested properties

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a livewire component that has about 25 properties.

`public $prop1=[], $prop2=[], $prop3=[]` etc. In my view, I'm looping over a collection and displaying a form that would normally have all these properties bound to it with `wire:model`. But the idea of the loop is throwing me off. I have something like `wire:model="prop1.{{$key}}"` but because I'm not declaring the property value in the render/mount functions, binding to the property array obviously isn't working. My question is what's the most efficient way to treat this scenario? Should I have a loop in the render or mount function that loops over the collection like so:

```
public function render()
    {
        $this->collection_items = Items::all();
        foreach($this->collection_items as $key=>$item)
        {
           $this->prop1[$key] = $item->prop1;
           $this->prop2[$key] = $item->prop2;
           $this->prop3[$key] = $item->prop3;
           ..........
        }
        return view('livewire.my-view');
    }
```

and then in my view I would be able to do `wire:model="prop1.{{$key}}"`? Or is there some other fancy way to do this without the loop in the render method that could accomplish this in a cleaner way?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of defining each and every property of your model separately, you can wrap them in an array:

`public $items = [];`

Then, you can use your key as subkey, and use [`fill`](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/properties#initializing-properties) to make quick work of your properties:

```php
foreach($this->collection_items as $key => $item) {
    $this->fill(["items.{$key}" => $item->getAttributes()]);
}
```

Then, all your `$attributeKey => $attributeValue` will be set under `$this->items[$key]`. In your view, you can then set your `wire:model` with dot notation in whatever way you wish to work these properties:

`wire:model="items.{{$key}}.prop1"`

You can also fill it as collection, simply by calling `$this->fill([$items => Items::all()])`, but then you can't `wire:model` to an attribute.

Comment: so, your answer seems to have worked quite well except for one thing. if I have `wire:model="items.1.prop1"` and `wire:model="items.1.prop2"` in the view, if i change prop1 first then change prop2, items.1 ONLY contains prop2. what ever is already in the array gets overwritten when the second item changes and the array only ever holds one value. any advice on this?

Comment: Livewire applies 'magic' to define and update properties. It uses your base properties to define what it should do when you update properties. Simply said: If you define a property as array, then Livewire will respect that. Therefore, if you were to have a checkbox, you **must** set it as array, otherwise you'll only ever get _one_ value. I usually don't do double nests, and so always already pre-define attributes in the public property (`array $users = ['name' => '']`). Perhaps you could do a foreach and ensure all keys are set on the nested models (with correct type)?